# Spotify API is not playing given track using React Native fetch

Tags: react-native, fetch-api, spotify

I am trying to use React Native to play a specific track using Spotify API. Some other endpoints have been working, but this one is not. It does correctly resume playback if it is stopped, but it does not begin playing the listed track(s), instead continuing the one that was already playing. t here is my Auth Token.

Here is my code:

```
fetch("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: "Bearer " + t,
        },
        json: {
          uris: [
            "spotify:track:4iV5W9uYEdYUVa79Axb7Rh",
            "spotify:track:1301WleyT98MSxVHPZCA6M",
          ],
        },
      }).then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Here is the response:

```
{"_bodyBlob": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "f51f5f89-ad63-4dc8-88ca-818a6f8ad7e5", "offset": 0, "size": 0}}, "_bodyInit": {"_data": {"__collector": [Object], "blobId": "f51f5f89-ad63-4dc8-88ca-818a6f8ad7e5", "offset": 0, "size": 0}}, "bodyUsed": false, "headers": {"map": {"access-control-allow-credentials": "true", "access-control-allow-headers": "Accept, App-Platform, Authorization, Content-Type, Origin, Retry-After, Spotify-App-Version, X-Cloud-Trace-Context, client-token, content-access-token", "access-control-allow-methods": "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, PATCH", "access-control-allow-origin": "*", "access-control-max-age": "604800", "alt-svc": "h3=\":443\"; ma=2592000,h3-29=\":443\"; ma=2592000", "cache-control": "private, max-age=0", "date": "Thu, 08 Jun 2023 00:43:05 GMT", "server": "envoy", "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000", "vary": "Accept-Encoding", "via": "HTTP/2 edgeproxy, 1.1 google", "x-content-type-options": "nosniff", "x-robots-tag": "noindex, nofollow"}}, "ok": true, "status": 204, "statusText": "", "type": "default", "url": "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/play"}
```